# Using Express and Node to connect HTML, CSS, and Javascript to a server

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have HTML, CSS, and Javascript programs that work perfectly together.  I've recently realized that I'm going to need a server to be able to complete some of my functionality.  I've created a local Node server using some tutorials.  After reading some suggestions, I'm trying to use Express to try to add the HTML, CSS, and Javascript to the Node, which are all in the same folder.  The code I have (below) just causes the browser to stay on loading.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8000;

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    //res.writeHead(200);
    //res.end("My first server!");
};

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need http module if you are using express...

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// '/' is the url you want to host your site

// 'public' is the folder in which you have the necessary frontend files

// and the main html should be named as 'index.html' inside 'public'

app.use('/', express.static('public'))

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('server on port 5000'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');  
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'css'));
app.use('/html',(req,res,next)=>{ 
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'HTML','text.html');});
app.listen(3000);
```